# Intel GMA 4500MHD driver for Acer Aspire 1425p

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu on my old Acer Aspire 1425p notebook.
I'm trying to watch 1080p videos from a Xiaomi Mijia 4k action cam. Videos are too laggy and impossible to watch.

It seems that material acceleration is not enabled. I just have profiles for mpeg2.

I searched for intel GMA 4500 MHD drivers but found nothing. Intel stopped recently its Graphics for Linux update tool. I tried to run Ubuntu 16.04, 17.10 and 18.04.

Do you have any clues on how to activate material acceleration for h.264 with this video card?